# Numbers written into a square grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics, discrete-optimization

I was working on a problem from The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Zietz, in the chapter called 'The extreme principle.' Here is the problem:

"The integers from 1 to $n^2$ are written into a nxn grid, no overlapping. Prove that there exists two adjacent cells whose numbers have difference at least n+1. Adjacent means touching horizontally, vertically, or diagonally."

I tried to consider the largest difference and assume that it was less than n+1, then add all possible differences together but this doesn't lead me to a contradiction when I try to put bounds on the rest of the differences.  How do I approach this problem?

(I'm on my phone so I apologize if these tags are not relevant)

Comment: Interesting that a natural layout (e.g. left to right, higher rows first) has no difference greater than $n+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- What is the difference between the extreme values in the square?
- What is the upper bound on the number of (horizontal, vertical or diagonal) steps between them on the shortest route between the extreme values?
- What is the lower bound on the average difference per step on the shortest route between the extreme values?

Comment: Aha thanks! So to get from 1 (the smallest) to n^2 (the largest) requires at most n-1 steps, so if we let the sequence b1 to b(n-1) be the differences we use to get there if we have all of them less than n+1 then the sum of the differences is less than n^2-1, contradiction. And if the number decreases along the way that only helps our cause more because if we subtract, we increase this number by making positive and then apply our inequality. Thanks for the help!